# Rspec Rake Task how to parse/simulate user input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

In my rake task I have:

```
namespace :example do
  desc "this does something"
  task :something, [:arg1] => :environment do |t, args|

   (some_irrelevant_code)

    print 'YES/ NO : '
    choice = STDIN.gets.chomp.upcase

    case choice
    when 'YES'
     do_something
     break
    when 'NO'
     break
    end

  end
end
```

In my spec I have:

```
require "spec_helper"
require "rake"

feature "Example" do
  before do
    load File.expand_path("../../../lib/tasks/example.rake", __FILE__)
    Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
  end

scenario "something" do
 Rake.application.invoke_task("example:something[rake_args_here]")
end
```

All is working fine, although I am having troubles finding a way to avoid having to type the user input in the console when running the test.

Basically I want the test to run and assume that the user is going to type "YES".

Please let me know if you have a solution for this or point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stub `STDIN` object like this `STDIN.stub(gets: 'test')`

or

`allow(STDIN).to receive(:gets).and_return('test')`

If both of them do not work then try:

`allow(Kernel).to receive(:gets).and_return('test')`

Comment: allow(STDIN).to receive(:gets).and_return('YES')
This worked perfectly. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3):

If you use `STDIN`, you're stuck, that's a constant. It's worth noting that using `STDIN` is not recommended because of this limitation.

If you use `$stdin`, the global variable equivalent and modern replacement, you can reassign it:

```
require 'stringio'
$stdin = StringIO.new("fake input")

$stdin.gets.chomp.upcase
# => "FAKE INPUT"
```

That means you can, for testing purposes, rework `$stdin`. You'll want to put it back, though, which means you need a wrapper like this:

```
def with_stdin(input)
  prev = $stdin
  $stdin = StringIO.new(input)

  yield

ensure
  $stdin = prev
end
```

So in practice:

```
with_stdin("fake input") do
  puts $stdin.gets.chomp.upcase
end
```

Comment: I havent tried this one as the solution in the previous reply worked but this seems to be a good solution as well. Thanks a lot for replying

Comment: With mocking, as in the other reply, you'll need to call specific methods for it to work properly. This is a more general purpose solution, but whatever works for you.